# How to apply ternary operator using JSON data on html - angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a JSON data which is something like:

```
$scope.user = {
     is_session_id: true,
     session_id: 'asdasdadssa',
     email     : 'abc@gmail.com'
}
```

Now, I want to assign `session_id` when 'is_session_by' is true, and `email` when `is_session_by` is false\null. The value is to be assigned to `id` of a div

```
<div id="{{ user.is_session_id}}  ?  {{  user.session_id }} : {{ user.email  }} " ></div>
```

I am making some silly mistake. please help

Its coming out like this when checked via "Inspect element":

```
<li ng-click="selectUser(user,$index)" 
  class="left clearfix ng-scope selected" 
  ng-class="{selected: selected_user.email === user.email}" 
  ng-repeat="user in user_list" 
  id="true  ?  asdasdadssa : abc@gmail.com">

  SOMETHING

 </li>
```

Comment: `is_session_by` is not the same with  `is_session_id`

Comment: Don't use three mustaches `{{ }}`. Enclose the entire expression in one set of double curly brackets `{{ }}`. See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code you need.

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{ user.is_session_by ? user.session_id : user.email  }}" ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `ng-attr-id` which parses your expression :

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{ user.is_session_id  ?   user.session_id  :  user.email  }} " ></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `ng-attr-id` t assign id with condition

```
<div  ng-attr-id="{{ user.is_session_id  ?   user.session_id :  user.email  }} " ></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simple and recommended for your problem

```
<div ng-attr-id="{{ user.session_id || user.email  }} " ></div>
```

No need a extra variable user.isSession_id

Answer (score -1):

Why you need this way if simple one is there.

In the controller :

```
 var user = {
         is_session_by: true,
         session_id: 'asdasdadssa',
         email     : 'abc@gmail.com'
    }

$scope.result = user.is_session_by  ?   user.session_id  :  user.email
```

In the html :

```
<div id="{{result}}" >{{result}}</div>
```

Comment: I think, there is no need of adding extra property in $scope when ng-attr-id can itself parse the expression

Comment: Its not about adding extra property.Its more about code readability,maintainability, testability.

Comment: @AkashKC anyway, you evalute it via {{}} ,it will take compilation time and same memory.

Comment: comment please.

Comment: @RIYAZ : I'd not done downvoting for your post. As comment, I would like to prefer ternary check in html itself rather than adding new property in $scope. As every field defined in the $scope has digest cycle which makes it dirty checking for those property in $scope. I don't want to have any dirty checking for property which can easily be computed as expression in html directive.